# Snowflake performance on different cloud platforms

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

given the same dataset and the same-sized virtual warehouse, is the query performance of the 3 cloud platforms that Snowflake runs on the same (within a reasonable margin of error)?
If not, which performs better/worse and is that due to the underlying storage, the compute power for each node, or a combination if the two?

Comment: They are equivalent.  Snowflake chooses the configurations of the warehouses to provide the same (or very similar) performance on each of the cloud platforms.  If you are trying to choose which platform to have Snowflake on, you should focus more on the platform tools that you wish to use along with Snowflake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved comment to an answer.

They are equivalent. Snowflake chooses the configurations of the warehouses to provide the same (or very similar) performance on each of the cloud platforms. If you are trying to choose which platform to have Snowflake on, you should focus more on the platform tools that you wish to use along with Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mike.

Answer (for those who might want to know) is in Mike's comment

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I completely agree with Mike Walton.

Snowflake is deployed on AWS, Microsoft Azure and Google Cloud.  I've run a number of queries including benchmarks across all three and the performance is about the same given the same virtual warehouse size and query.

In fact, Snowflake intentionally don't post the details of the underlying hardware used to by virtual warehouses, instead presenting them as "T-Shirt Sizes".  This is not out of secrecy, so much as "it doesn't actually matter".

The virtual warehouse on each platform consists of CPUs, memory and SSD and varies depending upon the platform.  My guess is, some platforms or operating systems are more efficient than others.

However, Snowflake does appear to have made great efforts to ensure every platform has the same experience.